# how to stop cursor from moving to the other side when in RTL in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

this issue happens when I try to edit text in multiline RTL text, the cursor does not go to the end of what was written instead it goes to the left, it's happening on both iOS and Android.

here's my `TextField`

```
TextField(
          controller: _Controller,
          autofocus: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          maxLines: null,
          maxLength: 500,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide:
                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade100, width: 2.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(5.0),
              ),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide:
                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade100, width: 2.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(5.0),
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide:
                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade100, width: 2.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(5.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Set the `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,` property in `TextField` and try again.

Comment: @dev-aentgs I have tried that, same behaviour.